# How to enter more than 1 row into dataGridView from textBox search

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using the below code to search for the inputted textBox ID in an accessdb and returning the row of data to a dataGridView. When I search for a second ID, the first row in the GridView is replaced, How can I make it save multiple rows?

The end goal of this project is to allow the user to search as many ID's as they like and pull the corresponding row of data into the gridview to then save all into a csv.

```
 private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn1.Open();

        //return ID, IMEI, ICCID, IMSI from dataBase
        OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("Select ID, IMEI,ICCID, IMSI from TBL where ID=@param1", conn1);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", txtScannedValue.Text);
        OleDbDataReader reader1;
        reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(reader1);

        //dataGridView1.DataSource= dt;
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).ImportRow(dt.Rows[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Data Found");
        }

        //reset textBox
        txtScannedValue.Text = "";

        conn1.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Even though this appears counter-intuitive of the whole “single” search approach…have you considered simply adding the next searched for row into the exiting data table? In other words, in your current code, if you get a row back from the search in `dt`… then, instead of setting THAT data table `dt` to the grid as a data source, simply do something like… `((DataTable)datagridView1.DataSource).ImportRow(dt.Rows[0]);` … ? …

Comment: This is just a suggestion; I would think it would be confusing to the user to see “Foo” in the search box and yet the grid displays “Foo” and “Bar.” If you want “multiple” search capabilities, I would consider redesigning the search UI to include “AND/OR” options for the user.

Comment: Thanks John, do you mean replace `dataGridView1.DataSource= dt;` with `((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).ImportRow(dt.Rows[0]);`. This gives an error - `No row at index 0`.
What I want is for the user to search a value, add it to the table and let them search and add as many more times as they need, atm it only works for 1 search

Comment: The error is saying that the “search” returned no results and `dt` is “empty”. You would obviously want to check for this to avoid the out-of-range error… `if(dt.Rows.Count > 0) {..}` … if no search results are returned, then there is nothing to add. This also assumes that the grid’s “current” data source is a `DataTable` with a similar schema.

Comment: I am now getting an error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object ` from the updated code above. I'm not sure what this means. Sorry I'm very new to c#

Comment: The error suggests the grid’s `DataSource` is `null`. If its `null`, then simply use `dt`. Add an `if` statement to check … `if (datagridview1.DataSource != null) { //import } else { dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; }`

Comment: Thanks a million John that is working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code is now working for using the textbox to search the database and enter multiple rows of code into the dataGridView. The question was answered in the comments on the op by JohnG. Posting here for future reference.

```
private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn1.Open();

        //return ID, IMEI, BatchNum, ICCID, IMSI from dataBase
        OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("Select ID, IMEI, BatchNum, ICCID, IMSI from TBLTest1 where ID=@param1", conn1);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", txtScannedValue.Text);
        OleDbDataReader reader1;
        reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(reader1);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.DataSource != null) {  
                ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).ImportRow(dt.Rows[0]);
            } 
            else 
            { 
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Data Found");
        }

        //reset textBox
        txtScannedValue.Text = "";

        conn1.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is - each time you press the `searchButton_Click` button you are running a query that returns 1 row only(`ID=@param1`) and then you are inserting ALL(which is always 1 in your case due to query) your searched rows to your `dataGridView` via `.DataSource()` bind.
To solve this I would recommend you to re-implement your data bindings:

I am assuming that `DataTable` is from `ADO.NET` so without changing a query you could bind your data something like this:

```cs
// this is pseudocode
private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

  var row = (DataGridViewRow) dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();

  var retrievedRow = getRowById(txtScannedValue.Text);
  if (retrievedRow is null) return;

  row.Cells[0].Value = retrievedRow.value1; // bind here you model fields
  row.Cells[1].Value = retrievedRow.value2;
  // ...

  dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
}

private void getRowById(string id) {
  conn1.Open();

  OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("Select ID, IMEI, TekNum, BatchNum, ICCID, IMSI from TBLTest1 where ID=@param1", conn1);
  cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", id);
  OleDbDataReader reader1;
  reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Load(reader1);

  DataRow row;
  if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
    row = dt.Rows[0];
  }

  conn1.Close();
  return row;
}
```

Comment: You will need to revise the code in the `searchButton_Click` event. It will fail on the last line of code… `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);` … if the grid uses a `DataSource` (which the OP is) , then, through code, you will not be able to “add” rows directly to the GRID with… `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);`… You will have to add the row to the grids `DataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a ListBox or ComboBox to present data they can recognize with the id available. To append rows, use DataTable.ImportRow.

Here a ComboBox is used to present, in this case employees and the DataGridView is initially populated with an empty DataTable.

Click a button to get a row to append to the underlying DataTable for the DataGridView.

**Model and data operations**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace AccessApplication.Classes
{
    public class EmployeesOperations
    {
        public static string ConnectionString =>
            "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=NorthWind.accdb";

        public static List<Employee> EmployeesList()
        {
            List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();
            using var cn = new OleDbConnection { ConnectionString = ConnectionString };
            using var cmd = new OleDbCommand() { Connection = cn };

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName  FROM Employees";

            cn.Open();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                list.Add(new Employee()
                {
                    Id = reader.GetInt32(0), 
                    FirstName = reader.GetString(1), 
                    LastName = reader.GetString(2)
                });
            }

            return list;
        }

        public static DataTable EmptyDataTable()
        {
            using var cn = new OleDbConnection { ConnectionString = ConnectionString };
            using var cmd = new OleDbCommand() { Connection = cn };

            cmd.CommandText = 
                "SELECT TOP 1 EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName FROM Employees";

            cn.Open();

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            table.Rows.Clear();

            return table;
        }
        public static DataTable SingleRow(int identifier)
        {
            using var cn = new OleDbConnection { ConnectionString = ConnectionString };
            using var cmd = new OleDbCommand() { Connection = cn };

            cmd.CommandText = 
                "SELECT TOP 1 EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName " +
                "FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID = @Id";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = identifier;
            cn.Open();

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

            return table;
        }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public override string ToString() => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
    }
}
```

**Form code**

```
public partial class EmployeeForm : Form
{
    private readonly BindingSource _employeesBindingSource = 
        new BindingSource();

    public EmployeeForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _employeesBindingSource.DataSource = EmployeesOperations.EmployeesList();
        EmployeesComboBox.DataSource = _employeesBindingSource;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = EmployeesOperations.EmptyDataTable();
    }

    private void GetSingleEmployeeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = ((Employee)EmployeesComboBox.SelectedItem).Id;
        DataTable table = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource);
        
        DataRow result = table.AsEnumerable()
            .FirstOrDefault(row => row.Field<int>("EmployeeID") == id);

        // only add if not already in the data grid view
        if (result == null)
        {
            table.ImportRow(EmployeesOperations.SingleRow(id).Rows[0]);
        }
    }
}
```